# SQL statement for getting top 5

Tags: sql

I have a table called `ads` and I want to get top 5 countries that ads comes from, and the most popular section in each of those 5 countries counties.

For example: India is top 1 and the user from India has chose properties section, Sweden is top 2 and Swedish popular section is Cars,...

Table name: `ads`

```
  [AdsID] Primary key
  ,[UID] 
  ,[Section]
  ,[Category]
  ,[Country]
  ,[State]
  ,[City]
  ,[AdsTit]
  ,[AdsDesc]
  ,[AdsPrice]
  ,[Img1]
  ,[Img2]
  ,[Img3]
  ,[Img4]
  ,[Img5]
  ,[Wtags]
  ,[AdsDate]
  ,[Website]
  ,[premium]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all ?

Comment: Description is somewhat ambiguous and unclear as well. You would be better supplying example data and desired results. eg I have no idea what `the most popular section in each of those 5 countries counties` means. Also `user from India` should be `users from India`?

Comment: Hi Ali I try this statement: Select Top 5 Country,Section from ads  but its not gives me the popular section of each country, so I didn't know how to do so I am asking the professional here

Comment: @Martin Smith thanks for your reply, I want to get the top 5 countries that ads comes from in my database and I want to get the most section selected by each country, hope that will be more clear :-)

Comment: When you say top 5 countries ... you just need any five countries or do u have a criteria for the top 5 as well? Cause your query Select top 5 is just getting 5 rows no conditions applied

Comment: Not massively more clear no. I take it that the mention of County is irrelevant then? I also assume that you mean users not user and there are multiple rows per country that need counting? What if there are ties for the number of adverts coming from a country? Or if there are ties for the most popular section within a country? Should both sections be displayed? Or more than 5 countries?

Comment: Which database? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle???

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah what u r saying is correct, so to be more specify and I hope I will be :-) the statement will collect top 5 countries that ads comes from whatever if x countries has 1000 ads and also show the top 5 of most section has been used by x country and as well as for others countries, and yes its users not user :-) I hope that I gives exactly what I want really I tried my best to explain what I looking for :-(

Comment: @TMNT2014 its MS SQL SERVER, I need the top 5 of countries that has more ads than others countries, and the top 5 of section used in each of those 5 countries to see each country their users which section are using more than others sections

Comment: This is a specific application of [tag:greatest-n-per-group].  We need more information to be able to help you though - like starting data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the top 5 countries that appear the most times in the `ads` table, and for each one of those countries you want to display its most frequent section.

The query below selects the top 5 countries by grouping the ads table by country and ordering the count and uses a subquery to select each country's most popular section.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Country , (
    SELECT TOP 1 Section FROM ads a2
    WHERE a2.Country = a1.Country
    GROUP BY Section
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) TopSection
FROM ads a1
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

To display the top 3 sections for the top 5 countries

```
SELECT TOP 5 Country , (
    SELECT TOP 1 Section FROM (
        SELECT Section, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank
        FROM ads a2    
        WHERE a2.Country = a1.Country
        GROUP BY Section
    ) t1 WHERE rank = 1
) Top1Section, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Section FROM (
        SELECT Section, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank
        FROM ads a2    
        WHERE a2.Country = a1.Country
        GROUP BY Section
    ) t1 WHERE rank = 2
) Top2Section, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Section FROM (
        SELECT Section, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank
        FROM ads a2    
        WHERE a2.Country = a1.Country
        GROUP BY Section
    ) t1 WHERE rank = 3
) Top3Section
FROM ads a1
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: that's amazing exactly that what I am looking for really thank you but can I show top 3 section of each countries Instead of 1 as above code

Comment: thanks again but could you check it as its gives me an error:   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.

Comment: I still getting this error  :-( : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: :-((((    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: thanksssssssss sooooooo much FuzzyTree I am really sorry to bother you

Comment: @Mike no problem, in the future please include in your question an example of a few rows of the desired result set

Comment: sure in next time I will do my best to make my question is more clear with examples

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Ad.[Country],
    Ad.[Category]
FROM 
    (SELECT
        [Country],
        [Category],
        RANK() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY [Country] ORDER BY [Country] DESC ) AS RANK
        FROM [Ads]
    ) AS Ad WHERE RANK <= 5
```